# Magento 2: How to call custom phtml file in another phtml file?

Tags: magento2, blocks, template

I'm trying to output custom phtml content of `Lapisbard_General::customer_account.phtml` in `Magento_directory::currency.phtml`

If I'm using below code, it works fine.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Lapisbard_General::customer_account.phtml")->toHtml();
```

But when I'm trying to use my custom block as below, it throws error

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Lapisbard\General\Block\CustomerAccount")->setTemplate("Lapisbard_General::customer_account.phtml")->toHtml();
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null in
>   /var/www/html/lapis/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php
>   on line 637

Block code:

```
namespace Lapisbard\General\Block;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class CustomerAccount extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
    public function isCustomerLoggedIn() {
        return $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

How can I make it work ?

Comment: add your block file code here

Comment: @John: Added block code. Kindly check.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace below code with your block code

```
namespace Lapisbard\General\Block;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class CustomerAccount extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
    public function isCustomerLoggedIn() {
        return $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Lapisbard\General\Block\CustomerAccount")->setTemplate("Lapisbard_General::customer_account.phtml")->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

If would be equal to 2x, use x^2 to calculate the underlying **customerdata**.

Store the data in an array and sort out the first 3 numbers.