# how to open new form in another phtml without url change

Tags: magento2, forms, address

I have put the form for `add new address` of `Address book` in address book index page itself without redirecting it to a new page for adding a new address.
I need to open the form html on click of `add address` without changing the url and redirecting to the `http://localhost/customer/address/new/` 
instead i want to remain in `http://localhost/customer/address/` page

1) `http://localhost/customer/address/` page UI
  [image]

2) on clicking `+ Add New Address` i need to put the html of the form which is at `http://localhost/customer/address/new/` url

[image]

So that Save button will work exactly like as it will in `/address/new` url form.

How to achieve this.

Since address has `/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book $block */`
and address new has `/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit $block */` block, so i cannot just put the `form phtml` from `edit.phtml` to `book.phtml`

I cannot put edit.phtml form code in book.phtml it throw error
as in edit.phtml  has it down block

```
<?php $_company = $block->getLayout()- 
>createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company::class) ?>
<?php $_telephone = $block->getLayout()- 
>createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Telephone::class) ?>
<?php $_fax = $block->getLayout()- 
>createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Fax::class) ?>
```

codes like this throw error

```
<?php if ($_company->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_company->setCompany($block->getAddress()->getCompany())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

where `$_company` variable is being used

Answer (score 1):

Add These code in your phtml

```
 <button>Add New Address</button>

<div class="address" style="display:none">
Your phtml code for new ADDRESS
<div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".address").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i cant just put html from edit.phtml to book.phtml, it throws error,

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103590/magento-2-how-to-call-custom-phtml-file-in-another-phtml-file