# How can i show tabs on frontend on custom product list page?

Tags: magento2

I want to show these tabs on front end in custom product list page. On the click of these tabs the related content will show.

[image: Refer Image Here]

Comment: you can call a static block right below the image section on pdp page and then you can provide url on click of which  the related tab content will show

Comment: Thanks for reply. You mean to say i have to create different static blocks for every link?

Comment: no just a single block and different static page for each section

Comment: and this is just a suggestion as there are lot of ways to achieve one things everyone has different thinking and ideas

Comment: @tamanna please check my answer and update me.

Comment: @Msquare Thank You for replay. I will try this and update you.

Comment: @tamanna have you got any error ? please update me.

Comment: @Msquare I tried but content of related tab is not loading on page.

Comment: @tamanna  please explain me more about what error you facing.

Comment: @Msquare I follow you code and add it to my phtml file. Tabs are visible, but content item is not displaying.

Comment: @Msquare I also try another solution. And i am too close too create same tab structure that i want but i am also have some confusion on that.Could you please help me on that?

Comment: please check my update last code in chat room  and i have also update on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add this tabs by adding this code

```
<div class="tab">
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Tab01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab03</a></li>
</ul> <!-- / tabs -->

<div class="tab_content">

    <div class="tabs_item">
        
        <h4>Tab 01 Neque ipsum dolor.</h4>
        <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, repellat facilis totam ab eos distinctio sint atque maiores! Dignissimos, molestiae, rem accusantium iure vitae voluptatum voluptas repudiandae deserunt dolore quis! Quisquam mollitia eius sed.</p>
    </div> <!-- / tabs_item -->

    <div class="tabs_item">
        
        <h4>Tab02 Maiores, suscipit</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, suscipit, eaque asperiores neque numquam nam possimus dolorem ipsa aspernatur reiciendis?</p>
    </div> <!-- / tabs_item -->

    <div class="tabs_item">
        
        <h4>Tab03</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, excepturi, minima, corporis deserunt quia quae sit officiis labore inventore autem a delectus consequuntur voluptatem modi eligendi similique sed nam vitae.</p>
    </div> <!-- / tabs_item -->
    
</div> <!-- / tab_content -->
</div> <!-- / tab -->
```

And for slide up/down content i added jquery

```
require(['jquery'], function($){
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() { 

    (function ($) { 
      $('.tab ul.tabs').addClass('active').find('> li:eq(0)').addClass('current');
      
        $('.tab ul.tabs li a').click(function (g) { 
          var tab = $(this).closest('.tab'), 
            index = $(this).closest('li').index();
          
          tab.find('ul.tabs > li').removeClass('current');
          $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
          
          tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_item').not('div.tabs_item:eq(' + index + ')').slideUp();
          tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_item:eq(' + index + ')').slideDown();
          
          g.preventDefault();
        } );
    })(jQuery);
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Try this code**

```
<div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"mage/tabs": {"openedState": "active"}}'>
    <div class="item title" data-role="collapsible">
        <a class="switch" data-toggle="trigger" href="#tab-white">White</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-white" class="item content" data-role="content">white content</div>

    <div class="item title" data-role="collapsible">
        <a class="switch" data-toggle="trigger" href="#tab-gold">Gold</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-gold" class="item content" data-role="content">Gold content</div>

    <div class="item title" data-role="collapsible">
        <a class="switch" data-toggle="trigger" href="#tab-silver">Silver</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-silver" class="item content" data-role="content">Silver Content</div>
</div>
```

> *you can call multiple phtml files into this content of  like this*

```
    <div class="item title" data-role="collapsible">
        <a class="switch" data-toggle="trigger" href="#tab-custom">Custom title</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-custom" class="item content" data-role="content">
        <?php
            echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\CustomerBlockName")->setTemplate("VendoreName_ModuleName::customtab.phtml")->toHtml();
        ?>
    </div>
```

> you can add multiple tab and also add your class name to apply your custom css.

[Tab Source link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_tabs.html)

[Call phtml file link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103600/82670)

***I Hope This Helps You.***